# How do you derive $M=-\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial H}\right)$?

Tags: thermodynamics, electrostatics, statistical-mechanics

I see all the time the following relations in thermodynamics/statistical-mechanics (considering a steady-state system):

$$\begin{align*}
dF&=-SdT-PdV-MdH-PdE\\
\implies M&=-\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial H}\right)_{T,V,H}\\
\implies P&=-\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial E}\right)_{T,V,H}\\
\end{align*}$$

where $F$ is the Hemholtz free energy, $M$ is the "magnetization", $P$ is the "polarization", $H$ is the "magnetic field", and $E$ is the "electric field". We understand the pairs $(M,H)$ and $(P,E)$ as being field-response conjugate pairs for the magnetic and electric energy respectively.

Ok, please tell me if/where I'm going wrong.

First, I think everybody that uses this notation is being really sloppy, because first off $M$ and $P$ in electrostatics represent magnetization and polarization density respectively, which have units of $1/\text{Volume}$. Also, $E$ can't possibly be the electric field because, well, just look at the units. It needs to be the electric displacement field, $D$. This seems to be universally taken care if in the magnetic-field case - the symbol $H$ is used, which correctly denotes the auxiliary magnetic field. But still, I think not being clear about this in textbooks or lecture notes on the subject is very sloppy.

Second, when I try to derive these simple relationships from electrostatics, I am always off by a small factor. For example, consider the electric-field energy case

$$\begin{align}
\bf{P}&=\epsilon_0\chi\bf{E}\\
\bf{D}&=\epsilon_0\bf{E}+\bf{P}\\
u&=\frac{1}{2}\bf{E}\cdot\bf{D}\\
&\\
\implies u&=\frac{1}{2\epsilon_0(1+\chi )}D^2\\
\rightarrow  du&=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0 (1+\chi)}D \,dD\\
&=\frac{1}{\chi}P\,dD
\end{align}
$$

I can't get rid of that $1/\chi$ sign! If I could get rid of it, I'd be fine: then $du=P\,dD$, put that in the thermodynamic formula for $dU$, and Legendre transform.

Comment: In guassian units E and D have the same units

Comment: @SeñorO Ah ok. After a reading a bit more into it I see that in Gaussian units, $\bf{P}$,  $\bf{M}$,  $\bf{H}$,  $\bf{B}$,  $\bf{E}$, and  $\bf{D}$ all have the same units. However, there is still that extra $1/\chi$ sign that I can't get rid of, even in Gaussian units.